# How do I add device flags to an existing docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

The (already created and tailored) docker container, which is on a Tegra TX2 host, was created with the priveleged flag.

I want to add devices from my Tegra TX2 host to the container, but 'docker run --device=...' would create a new container. How can I do this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker update` is what you would use if you want to update the configuration of a container. Unfortunately there is no way to add a new device without recreating the container.

For more information on what can be updated [check the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/).

Comment: Hi Esteban, thanks for your great answer (and also nice teeth). Actually in my rush I forgot to realise I did already mount the volume /dev:/dev when I ran the container, which is the folder on the host where I want to get the devices from. So surely this means I do have access to the devices in the /dev folder of the host? How can I use them in the container?

Comment: Well that depends on which device and what do you want to do with it.

Comment: I'm trying to use a NVidia's nvcamera-daemon service to run a GStreamer pipeline. I've mounted /dev, /proc, /sys on the container. Atm, when I run the pipeline in the container I get: "Error: Connecting to camera_daemon failed". There are some files in the /dev folder of the host like 'nvhost-gpu' which I think may help solve this, not sure if these would automatically be recognised & used by the container? Maybe I need to use 'docker service' / 'docker service create'. The actual nvcamera-daemon file is in /etc/systemd/system of the host so is not mounted, not sure if I need this.

Comment: `docker service` has nothing to do with this, is a command for interacting with swarm clusters. I don't have enough knowledge of `Tegra` or the services you're trying to use to help you. This goes beyond a simple docker question.